# How to show customer registration date on the Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to add the customer registration date on the sales Order Grid.

I added the bolow code in **`app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php`**

```
$this->addColumn('customer_created_at', array(
            'header' => "Date d'inscription",
            'index' => 'customer_created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));
```

I also added in a **`config.xml`** file

```
<fieldsets>
    <customer_account>
        <created_at>
            <to_quote>customer_created_at</to_quote>
       </created_at>
    </customer_account>
    <sales_convert_quote>
        <to_order>customer_created_at</to_order>
    </sales_convert_quote>
</fieldsets>
```

I managed to diplay the field in the grid, but can't get the right data.

I also added a **customer_created_at** column in **sales_flat_order**, **sales_flat_order_grid** and in **sales_flat_quote**.

Thank you

Comment: What are the fields you want to display in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace your code in file `config.xml`

**From:**

```
<fieldsets>
    <customer_account>
        <created_at>
            <to_quote>customer_created_at</to_quote>
       </created_at>
    </customer_account>
    <sales_convert_quote>
        <to_order>customer_created_at</to_order>
    </sales_convert_quote>
</fieldsets>
```

**To:**

```
<fieldsets>
    <customer_account>
        <created_at>
            <to_quote>customer_created_at</to_quote>
        </created_at>
     </customer_account>                    
     <sales_convert_order>
        <customer_created_at>
            <to_quote>*</to_quote>
        </customer_created_at>
     </sales_convert_order>
     <sales_convert_quote>
        <customer_created_at>
            <to_order>*</to_order>
        </customer_created_at>
     </sales_convert_quote>
</fieldsets>
```

**Note:** After clear all magento cache in admin side and try again

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should not add the separate columns in the tables.

Add new event observer:

```
   <events>
        <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
            <observers>
                <add_custom_columns_select>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>addCustomColumnsSelect</method>
                </add_custom_columns_select>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
   </events>
```

Add method like:

```
/**
 * Add custom columns in sales order grid collection
 *
 * Event: sales_order_grid_collection_load_before
 *
 * @param $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function addCustomColumnsSelect($observer)
{
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order' || Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'customer') {
        /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection $orderGridCollection */
        $orderGridCollection = $observer->getOrderGridCollection();
        /** @var Varien_Db_Select $select */
        $select = $orderGridCollection->getSelect();
        $select->joinLeft(
            array('customers' => $orderGridCollection->getTable('customer/entity')),
            '`main_table`.`customer_id` = `customers`.`entity_id`',
            array('customer_created_at' => 'created_at'));
    }

    return;
}
```

Change your code for column:

```
$this->addColumn('customer_created_at', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Customer Created At'),
        'index' => 'customer_created_at',
        'filter_index' => 'customers.created_at',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'width' => '100px',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing has to understand is in function

```
  protected function _prepareCollection()
   {
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    /***********Show All available fields*************/
     zend_debug::dump($collection->getData())
   /***********Show All available fields*************/
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
   }
```

Add the line zend_debug::dump($collection->getData())
This will show all available fields that can be use in Grid.

To add **customer registration date** you have to add the Join query respective customer id in the collection.